# What does MOS and RA stand for in IT project?

Tags: software-development, documentation, performance

My customer asked if I can do an MOS and RA.  RA should be risk analysis if I'm not mistaken.  But what is MOS?

Comment: RA=risk assessment MOS= Method of Statement

Answer (score 7):

### Context Matters

Acronyms and initalisms are useful shorthand when discussing a problem domain with others who share the same lexicon. However, such shorthand is highly contextual. For example, an "R.A." might mean Risk Analysis in an information security context, but a Residential Assistant in a college dormitory.

### Inspect-and-Adapt Your Communications Plan

If you want to know what a customer means by a given acronym, just ask. Strangers on the Internet won't know what the *client* thinks a given acronym means, especially if they're using an acronym or concept in an unusual way (as sometimes happens in the real world).

Better yet, **ensure that your project maintains a glossary** that includes the acronyms, initialisms, and domain-specific terms that your project actively uses. This avoids a great deal of ambiguity, and can be surprisingly effective at improving project communication.

Comment: In the domain I am currently in, RA means Rental Agreement ;-)